# Javascript error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

> Error: invalid regular expression flag
>   b Source File:
>   http://localhost/media/javascript/global.js
>   Line: 4, Column: 19 Source Code:
>           url: /home/blog,

```
$("#blog").click(function () {
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$.ajax ({
    url: /home/blog,
    type: "POST",
    success : function (html) {
        $("#someDiv").append(html);
    }
});
```

});

I cant figure out what the error is, does my URL need to be in a string? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the url to be `"home/blog"`

Answer (score 0):

Im not a Javascript Guru, but from that sample, I would of thought that you need to put the URL in quotes, so it should read:

```
url: "/home/blog",
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put your `url` in quotes.

`url: "home/blog",`

When you're looking at the errors returned, make note of the **column and line numbers** - they can really help and give a massive indication to where you may have gone wrong.